# jQuery How to create and fire dynamic hotkeys (keycode and :not() selector?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, keycode

I have a web app that I'm working on that I would like the user to be able to define and trigger hotkeys dynamically. I hope someone can help me out?

I've created a [JSFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jwQqQ/4/) with the pertinent HTML.

Here's my javascript:

```
// Assign Hotkey (this seems to be working)
$('input.hotkey').keydown( function(event) {
var hkey = event.keyCode;
if ( hkey == $('span#hk').text()){
    alert('This key is already in use');
} else
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('span#hk').text(hkey);
});

// Fire Hotkey (the problem might be here?)
$(document).not('input').keydown( function (event) {
    var hkey = event.keyCode;
    if (hkey == $('span#hk').text()){
         $("span#hk:contains("+hkey+")").parent().click();
    }
});

// Play Selected Track
$('#track').live('click', function () {
    // Fake Function
    var title = $('#title', this).text();
    alert(title + ' is playing...');
});
```

Note: I have already used the 'space' and 'left/right' arrow keys as global hotkeys - is there a way to protect/prevent them from being assigned?

Is there a better selector to use than .not('input') to prevent firing the track during input typing?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).not('input')` does not find all elements that are not `input` tags.  It finds all the document nodes (of which there is one) that are not input elements (which is all one of them).  All you've done is attached the handler to the `document`.  Because parent elements are notified of events triggered on their descendants, all `keydown` events are handled by this function.

You should make use of [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target) instead:

```
$(document).keydown( function (event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') {
        var hkey = event.keyCode;
        if (hkey == $('span#hk').text()){
            $("span#hk:contains("+hkey+")").parent().click();
        }
    }
});
```

The `if` statement means the handler does not do anything if the event originated on an `input` element.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked brilliantly in targeting the input/document event!